# Conditional expectation unique?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, stochastic-calculus

Let $A \subset B$ be a subalgebra. This means that $E(X|A)$ is also $B$ measurable. Now, if I can show that $E(X|B)$ is also $A$ measurable, does this imply that the conditional expectations are the same?

I know that conditional expectations are uniquely defined. But I don't see where

$\int_{H} E(X|A) = \int_{H} X $ for all $H \in B$ follows from.

Comment: Do you mean for all random variables $X$? Since, one could get trivial counter-examples with the random variable $X=0$.

Comment: Also, there are allowed to be differences between "versions" of conditional expectations, so long as the differences arise with probability 0.

Comment: no, I mean only for one random variable.

Comment: Well, the all-zero function is measurable with respect to any sigma algebra.

Comment: and how does this contradict my question?

Comment: How does it not?  You are trying to conclude that two sigma algebras are the same, correct? So what if you take two different sigma algebras but define $X=0$?

Comment: Notice the ambiguity in your question:  What does "they are the same" mean?  I take that to mean "sigma algebras $A$ and $B$ are the same."  I realize now that one might interpret it as "the conditional expectations are the same."

Comment: I mean, the conditional expectations are the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30793/discussion-between-michael-and-doctorcombine).